# Program crashes when trying to dereference non null pointer to BYTE aka(unsigned char)

Tags: c++, c++11, dereference, unsigned-char

I'm trying to dereference the `modBaseAddr` (`BYTE*` aka `unsigned char*`) member of a [MODULEENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684225(v=vs.85).aspx) structure in `tlhelp32.h`. But when I try to dereference it my program crashes. I did an `if` statement to make sure it wasn't a `nullptr`. It isn't but my program still crashes. Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD pid = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    MODULEENTRY32 mod_entry;
    mod_entry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    HANDLE procH;

    cout << "PID: " << flush;
    cin >> pid;

    procH = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE|TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pid);
    if(procH == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "Failed to retrieve process handle" << endl;
        CloseHandle(procH);
        return 1;
    }
    if(!(Module32First(procH, &mod_entry))){cout << "Mod32 1st failed\n";CloseHandle(procH);return 1;}

    if(mod_entry.modBaseAddr == nullptr){cout << "modBaseAddr is empty\n";CloseHandle(procH);return 1;}
    BYTE mod_baseaddr = *mod_entry.modBaseAddr; //<-------------------Causes program to crash.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the address in the address space of some other process, not yours. You may be looking for `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That worked. Thank you very much! If you make this comment into a an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik After thinking about it, if `modBaseAddr` references the virtual address space of another process shouldn't it just interpret the address as apart of it's own process since two programs can have the same virtual address(both have a 0x1 address and so forth)?

Comment: @Jdoggy - Yes it would. Apparently the other process (also) has some addresses not used in this process.

Comment: So you know that in process X, some module is loaded at address `modBaseAddr`. What exactly do you hope to achieve by reading address `modBaseAddr` in an unrelated process Y? Yes, you might perhaps get lucky: that address may be valid in Y, so you may be able to read a byte of memory - but then what? That byte of memory doesn't mean anything, as `modBaseAddr` doesn't have any particular significance to Y, the way it does to X. It's kind of like looking for the keys under the street light - not because you lost them there, but  because that's where light is, so searching is easier.

Comment: So basically it's a segmentation fault?